# Count Numerical Values Separated by Comma

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is there a formula to count the number of numerical values that are separated by a comma in a single cell?

Comment: Just count the number of commas and add 1.... 1,2,3,4,5 (4+1)  or is some of the data not numeric and we have to examine that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187667

Assuming string in A1:A1... but you can alter to just be a cell or a range...

```
=SUM(LEN(A1:A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A1,",","")))/LEN(",")+1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily by searching the finding the number of commas in the cell and adding 1.

If the cell you want to search is A1 then use this:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```